# SSH tunneling not working in some applications but working on some ports

Tags: ssh, proxy, port, ssh-tunnel

So I have setuped an ssh servr in azur and i am accessing it with bitvise client, which is ok till now. But the problem is that some application are still not working i.e not using the ssh traffic/proxy.

[Bitvise login details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EemFX.png)

[Windows proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRgyq.png)

[Bitwise proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWJL0.png)

I am expecting all the traffic from my pc to go thorugh the ssh tunnel.